# VueJS: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'rol' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a function for login
I am getting the 'cannot read property rol of undefined' error: here is my vueJs code:

```
methods: {
    send: function() {
      this.error = null;
      this.showLoader = true;
      this.$http
        .post("/login", new FormData(document.getElementById("LoginUser")), {
          reponseType: "json"
        })
        .then(response => 
        {
            localStorage.setItem("role", response.data.data.rol);
            location.href = "/";
          },
          fail => {
            this.showLoader = false;
            this.password = "";
            for (let message of fail.data.data.messages) {
              this.error = this.$t(
                message.message.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_")
              );
            }
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

what am i doing wrong? Thanks
I have been trying to solve this for a long time but I have not succeeded

Comment: It means that your `response.data` has no property `data`, so you're trying to access the property `rol` of an `undefined` value. Perhaps you didn't mean to add the second `.data`? Log `response.data` to see if it's what you expected.

Comment: No that I already tried and it is not

Comment: you can user like this    if(response.data.data){
            localStorage.setItem("role", response.data.data.rol);
                location.href = "/";
      }

Comment: @SebasCarrillo What does logging `response.data` show?

Comment: the response.data shows me undefined

Comment: with the condition it no longer shows me the error, apparently the data is not arriving

Comment: could you add this response in your quesion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per the documentation for `vue-resource`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md), the `response` object has no property `data`. What you're looking for is either `response.body` or `response.json()` to resolve `response.body` into a JSON object.